# are C++11 user defined literals slower than normal type casting?

Tags: c++, user-defined-literals

1) is any of these faster than the other at runtime? which and why?
2) does this occur at compile time or runtime?

```
unsigned short operator"" _ushort( unsigned long long arg ){ return arg; }

unsigned short my_var = 0x1234;          // using type and literal
auto my_var = unsigned short(0x1234);    // using auto and casting literal to type
auto my_var = 0x1234_ushort;             // using auto and user defined literal to cast
```

**edit:** does using *constexpr* help it?

```
constexpr unsigned short operator"" _ushort( unsigned long long arg ){ return arg; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us see from the generated assemblies... using this tool: https://gcc.godbolt.org

The assembly produced by clang is: (modified your code to compile)

For this input,

```
inline unsigned char operator "" _kx ( unsigned long long arg ){ return arg; }

unsigned char my_var = 0x14;          // using type and literal
auto my_var2 = (unsigned char) 0x1234;    // using auto and casting literal to type
auto my_var3 = 0x1234_kx;             // using auto and user defined literal to cast
```

The assembly generated is

```
my_var:
        .byte   20                      # 0x14

my_var2:
        .byte   52                      # 0x34

my_var3:
        .byte   52                      # 0x34
```

So, there is no performance hit... rather a gain in flexibility....
Though the operator function seems to still be created in certain compiler versions under certain flags.... The values are initialized at compile-time

https://godbolt.org/g/YuJyQd

Answer (score 1):

All of these are initialized at compile time, and thus there is no runtime impact to any of them.